# Why many expert players just disconnect on the last round in Hearthstone?

Tags: hearthstone

I'm a (not too) novice Hearthstone player, this month I'm on rank 12 in ranked mode and many, many, many times when my opponents feels that I'm gonna win the fight they just quit the game; that is, my opponents simply disconnects on the last round when they feel that they are gonna lose the match.

I really doubt that they just close the game entirely because rage or because life suddenly needs them, as there are just far too many times that I have seen players disconnecting on the last round  always in the same circumstances. This only appears to be expert players (people that are on high levels of ranked mode), it's not a normal behavior for all players because a normal player just would use the *Concede* button which I understand to be faster.

I'm sure they share the same reason to disconnect on the last round (i.e. quit entirely from Hearthstone) when they are gonna lose a match, so I'm wondering if there is an explanation, for example a kind of official trick or legal (as far as Hearthstone's term of use) exploit/cheat or something else to avoid the Hearthstone algorithm to record their loss when they re-log the client and avoid downgrading in the rank?

I'm aware that in theory when a user closes the game or disconnects during a match the Hearthstone's system automatically awards the win to your opponent; however, I have witnessed this behavior too many times in simiular circumstances for it to be a coincidence.

My question is: Is there some advantageous reason in Hearthstone I've overlooked that these *experts* are quitting on the last round when they are going to lose

Comment: Not on HS, but I'd disconnect to prevent the other player to taunt me, thus further annoy me after the loss, similarly I'd taunt if I win. in this case they may value their time and wish to save a minute and quickly jump into the next battle instead of waiting on all the animations etc. (This is not an answer because of the first sentence)

Comment: Fun fact: Some time ago leaving the game instead of conceding was actually the only way to avoid queued BM moves by the winning player.  Waiting for all those animations to finish could have  taken a good amount of time, so it was faster to just leave the game and restart. This is no longer needed though, since conceding is now instant as well.

Comment: Considering you say it happens so often, my guess would be that either there's a problem with the game/your client where a concede seems to be a disconnect for you, or that a dc loses less elo than a surrender.

Comment: Another theory is that players that play on mobile only play a game or two at a time, so they just exit the game when they're going to lose, instead of conceding then exiting.

Comment: it's also a (false) misconception amongst several Hearthstone players I have talked to, that quitting the client before actually losing/conceding will somehow avoid registering the game as a loss with the resulting drop in rank.

Comment: I hate to 'blame the victim' here, but do you emote a lot?

Comment: @Donnie C No, really I do nothing to offend or disturb players, If I do that then I could understand they leave in last round for trolling me or something like that, If I ask the question is because is strange that behavior while I do nothing more than win the match, and my opponents, those who just disconnect, they also doesn't seems trolls.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It seems it must be a causality. Disconnecting from a match permanently counts the same as a concede, so there is no gameplay or statistical advantage to do so, however:

- They may be quitting entirely from playing the game, and instead of quitting out from the main-menu, just close the game straightup.
- It may be quicker to quit out of the game and reboot it instead of waiting through the conceding explosion animation, the XP gain animation, the rank win/loss animation, and the fade-in to the main menu. Especially if they're running on an SSD (Laymans: A type of Hard-drive which means data loads faster) or a high-end rig, it'll certainly be quicker.
- It's possible they're incredibly mad and just do it out of rage

Comment: +1, Just wanted to comment and say sometimes I get disconnected if my internet craps out on me or what have you and it will ALWAYS count as a loss, unless I can reconnect in time to get back into the game, not sure on the time limit to do so, but it is not very long.

Comment: I think the game has a way to detect a client quit vs. A game crash or internet dc. When they "quit" the concede is almost instant, but I've seen people not do things for turns as their internet took a while to kick back

Answer (score 4):

If you only play a single game of Hearthstone at a time, or you are playing your last game for a while, it is faster to exit the program rather than conceding. Personally, I play on my phone and almost always it's one single match. I can't leave Hearthstone running in the background or else it uses too much power, so I have to force close the app immediately after I'm done. Since I'm going to do that anyway, when I want to concede the match, I just close the app. To my opponent, it looks like I disconnected.

Comment: "it is faster to exit the program rather than conceding" I would encourage people to not do this. Sure, it's faster but also slower for the other player. So let me correct myself - only do it if you dislike the other player. Otherwise it's much nicer to give a 'Well Played' and concede.